# FreeBSD: adding ip alias to interface breaks network on primary ip

Tags: networking, freebsd, ip, jails, ifconfig

I am trying to add an alias to my network card (I would like to use jails) on my FreeBSD box. It is running version 10.2-RELEASE-p7 (generic amd64 kernel).
The machine is running in a Hyper-V virtual machine, but I experience the same thing on my physical box, the only difference is that is is running the x86 (32bit) version of the same 10.2 kernel.

The network interface hn0 has a static IP address: 192.168.0.51/24, my default router is 192.168.0.1. Everything works fine, until I add the alias:

```
ifconfig hn0 inet 192.168.0.200/32 alias
```

This creates the alias on hn0 as ifconfig shows:

```
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 16384
    options=600003<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,RXCSUM_IPV6,TXCSUM_IPV6>
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000
    nd6 options=21<PERFORMNUD,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
hn0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
    options=31b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,VLAN_HWTAGGING,TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 00:15:5d:00:0f:00
    inet 192.168.0.51 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.0.255
    inet 192.168.0.200 netmask 0xffffffff broadcast 192.168.0.200
    nd6 options=29<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
```

The problem is that as soon as I have the alias in place, I cannot reach any host outside my subnet (even when using the host's IP address). E.g. a google nameserver:

```
ping 8.8.8.8
ping 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
```

However, I can ping anything using the alias as the source:

```
ping -S 192.168.0.200 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 192.168.0.200: 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=0 ttl=56 time=11.137 ms
...
```

If the alias is created by jail(8) when starting a jail, the jail using the alias has network access, while the host does not. After removing the alias I have to restart the services netif and routing to regain network access on the primary IP of the host.

When the jail runs, I can ssh into it or I can ping it using the IP alias.

Based on the fact that I cannot ping external nodes using their IP my guess would be that there is something wrong with the routing. Name resolving does not work as my box is unable to reach the DNS servers. Here is my netstat -rn output before adding the alias:

```
Destination        Gateway            Flags      Netif Expire
default            192.168.0.1        UGS         hn0
127.0.0.1          link#1             UH          lo0
192.168.0.0/24     link#2             U           hn0
192.168.0.51       link#2             UHS         lo0
```

and after the alias has been created:

```
Destination        Gateway            Flags      Netif Expire
default            192.168.0.1        UGS         hn0
127.0.0.1          link#1             UH          lo0
192.168.0.0/24     link#2             U           hn0
192.168.0.51       link#2             UHS         lo0
192.168.0.200      link#2             UHS         lo0
192.168.0.200/32   link#2             U           hn0
```

IPv6 values are omitted as I have disabled IPv6 by adding

```
ipv6_network_interfaces="none"
ipv6_activate_all_interfaces="NO"
```

to /etc/rc.conf

I am no expert at network setup, but I have read everything I could find about jails and IP aliases but I haven't found anything helpful. Maybe I am overlooking something trivial, but I have no idea what breaks network access on the host.

Comment: I can also repro the issue from regular configuration if — and only if — I specify the interface card, (ie `ip4.addr += "em0|1.2.3.4"`). To provide IPs only doesn't break network (`ip4.addr += "1.2.3.4"`). To flush routes and reconfigure them works well (or `/etc/rc.d/netif restart ; /etc/rc.d/routing restart`).

Answer (score 1):

net mask is too wide, try

```
ifconfig hn0 inet 192.168.0.200/24 alias
```

Alias must be on same network usually.

Comment: Thanks, I have just tried it, but unfortunately the result is the same. Moreover, jail creates the alias automatically with a /32 netmask (maybe it can be changed somehow).

Comment: Aliases within the same subnet usually use a /32 netmask. It's documented in ifconfig(8)